# Defining a real scalar equal to an 1x1 matrix

Tags: fortran

Let A and B be matrices of size 1 times n and n times 1, respectively.
Then the multiplication of A with B is a 1 times 1 matrix.

Which is the better way to assign the value of `MATMUL(A,B)` to a real number `x`?

I would like to write:

```
x=MATMUL(A,B)  ! <<--- but this is wrong.
```

The above expression is wrong because I'm trying to assign a 1 times 1 matrix to a real number.

My solution is to define a 1 times 1 matrix C and with this:

```
C=MATMUL(A,B)
x=C(1,1)         ! <--- this solution is ok, but is too long
```

But, there exists a better way to assign `MATMUL(A,B)` to the real number `x`?

The entire code with my question is as follow:

```
PROGRAM testing
  !
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL :: A(1,2),B(2,1),C(1,1),x
  !
  A(1,1)=1.0; A(1,2)=3.5
  B(1,1)=2.0; B(2,1)=5.0
  C=MATMUL(A,B)               ! it is ok
  x=MATMUL(A,B)               ! it is wrong
  x=C(1,1)                    ! it is ok     <--- exists a better way ??
  !
END PROGRAM testing
```

Comment: I think you missed a version or two of FORTRAN...

Comment: You could do `x=sum(matmul(a,b))`. Not sure I care for that for readability though.  If I was doing this often I'd probably define a little wrapper function to return the `(1,1)` element of an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have noticed that it is not possible to do intrinsic assignment of an array to a scalar (and `C` is a rank-2 array of size 1).  `x=C(1,1)` is the correct way to do such assignment from the single element of `C` to the scalar `x`.

There are other ways to abstract that correct assignment statement, but probably little value in doing so.

In your specific case, however, there is alternative.  Rather than `matmul`, consider `dot_product`.

```
x = DOT_PRODUCT(A(1,:), B(:,1))  ! Scalar result, intrinsic assignment allowed.
```

Answer (score 1):

per my comment, you can write a very simple function to extract the first element of an array:

```
real function first(matrix) !return the (1,1,1,..) element of an array
real, intent(in) :: matrix(*)
first=matrix(1)
end function
```

simply use as:

```
real :: a(1,2),b(2,1),x
...
x=first(matmul(a,b))
```

note if you want to make sure this is only used for a `dimension(1,1)` array you need to use an explicit interface and do:

```
real function first(matrix)
real, intent(in) :: matrix(:,:)
if(.not.all(shape(matrix).eq.[1,1]))reporterror()
first=matrix(1,1)
end function
```